# Assigning multiple values in an inline if/else statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write an inline if/else statement that assigns two values based on a single condition. Something to the effect of:

```
x = y = 0
value = 11
threshold = 5

x, y = x+1, 0 if value <= threshold else x, y = x-1, value
```

I'd expect this code to result in `x = -1` and `y = 11`.
When I run this, I get this error: `SyntaxError: cannot assign to literal`.
I played around with parenthesis, but couldn't get anything to work.

Is there a way to do this?  I can work around this, but this would be especially convenient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need parentheses, and the extra `x, y =` after the `else` is not needed as well:

```py
>>> x = y = 0
>>> value = 11
>>> threshold = 5
>>>
>>> x, y = (x+1, 0) if value <= threshold else (x-1, value)
>>> x
-1
>>> y
11
```

Note that without parentheses, you have a 3-tuple on the right side:

```py
>>> x,y = x-1, value if value <= threshold else x+1, 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

It is parsed as:
`x+1`, `0 if value <= threshold else x-1`, `value`

Comment: @LCVcode The typo is extraneous to the problem.  I'll edit it out of both and we can delete these comments.